# Phonegap : Plugin development tutorial for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Sorry if this question was already asked.

I want a complete tutorial on phonegap plugin development in iOS, i have visited this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) but was not able to understand where to add the code in the native part, if any one has a good link on this topic do let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check below tutorial for phonegap plugin development for iOS i found it useful

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CGIQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmoduscreate.com%2Fbuilding-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios%2F&ei=VI-lUuDLCoKQrQeP6oC4BA&usg=AFQjCNG-YGsS8sK6qjWGAcb6JjRHmM_Fxg&bvm=bv.57752919,d.bmk